Problemas con Firebase deploy
Tengo un problema con firebase al momento de aplicar el firebase deploy. Tengo un proyecto que al intentar hacer el deploy, solo sube los archivos .html sin formato, no sube los archivos ni las carpetas asignadas para el css y js.
Este es un ejemplo de lo que me muestra la consola, sucede con todos los assets

Esta es la estructura actual del firebase.json


{
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}



¿Alguna pista de lo que pueda estar pasando?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
